# QuickBlox - How to send data during video call?

Tags: android, video-streaming, quickblox, quickblox-android

Is there any way to send some data to opponent during live video call? We have a requirement to send configuration data to opponent based user's action on video call screen. Or is it something like that we need to open chat session between user's in background and send data on that channel?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send data on some step of call, you can use `userInfo` field of callback, for example, if you want send data when accept call, use next code:

```
QBRTCSession qbrtcSession = ...;
Map<String, String> someAdditionalData = ...;

qbrtcSession.acceptCall(someAdditionalData);
```

and all participants will get this info in callback

```
onCallAcceptByUser(QBRTCSession session, Integer userId, Map<String, String> userInfo);
```

If you want send data in any time during call, you can use QuickBlox System Notifications feature, more [there](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#System_notifications).

Comment: This is great!! This is what we were looking for, will try and let you know if we face any issue.